# Offline secondary replica brought primary replica to halt

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

I have an AG built on a 2 node WSFC. When the secondary replica went down for patching last weekend, the primary basically locked up and wouldn't allow any connections or queries.

2 nodes are on the same site (sql0 and sql1); 1 node is an Azure DR (sqlm).  All 3 nodes have 1 vote. No shared disk; No cluster witness, just the AG listener.

Messages in the SQL Server log show the disconnect from the secondary, then a bunch of "Always On Avail Group Connection with secondary db terminated...", then a bunch of "Remote harden of transaction failed", then login failures followed.

If the Windows Cluster was offline during the shutting down of sql1, why was there no notification from AG sql0 that there was an imminent failure ahead?
What needs to happen to have the primary continue to function when the secondary is down?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the Windows Cluster configuration? Are both servers on same site? Is there a quorum witness of any kind configured? Any custom configuration for node vote? Availability Group will stay online only if the Windows cluster is online.

Comment: Yes, thank you. 
2 nodes are on same site (sql0 and sql1); 1 node is an Azure DR (sqlm)
All 3 nodes have 1 vote
No shared disk; No cluster witness, just the AG listener  
Messages in SQL log show the disconnect from the secondary, then a bunch of "Always On Avail Group Connection with secondary db terminated..." then a bunch of "Remote harden of transaction failed" then login failures followed.
If the Windows Cluster was offline during the shutting down of sql1, why was there no notification from AG sql0 that there was an imminent failure ahead?

Comment: So sqlm is basically the quorum witness. Did you check Windows cluster events? If sql0 lost contact with sqlm, Windows cluster will go down without any warning, along with the AG.

Comment: Why do you say that sqlm is the witness?  Because it's the 3rd node? Or some other reason? Can I see what the witness is in FCM?  It has been recently added and the issues may have started at that time. IDK. (I'm the DBA and didn't create the cluster)
The cluster events just show a lot of these: "The backup operation for the cluster configuration data has been canceled. The cluster Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS) writer received an abort request." for sqlm.

Comment: A Windows cluster will stay up only if a majority of voting nodes can contact each other. With 3 nodes, you always need at least 2 nodes up and able to talk to each other.  So yes, sqlm is kind of a quorum witness in your setup.  Your Windows admins really need to make sure the cluster health is #1 and is properly configured.